# How to make preview photos bigger in prettyphoto

Tags: javascript, jquery, prettyphoto

Hello I have the prettyphoto plugin included in my theme. When I press a photo it opens in preview mode. I want to make the preview mode bigger and I can't manage to do that. I tried to change the following values and absolutely nothing changed:

allow_resize: true,
allow_expand: true,
default_width: 3000,
default_height: 3000,

https://imokasa.ro/properties/apartament-4-camere-calea-dumbravii/

Please help! The people from the theme support told me that they do not offer support for pretty photo and their documentation doesn't mention that part: http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/

Many thanks!

Comment: Provide a demo/jsfiddle/some code, otherwise its hard to understand the problem and help.

Comment: @Dekel hi here's the whole prettyphoto code: http://pastebin.com/4ervVst1

Comment: Use jsfiddle or snippet here in stackoverflow to create a working example